oauth2-server: how to implement Authorization Code Grant
I am attempting to use oauth2-server to implement an Authorization Code Grant scenario using this example: https://merlino.agency/blog/step-by-step-how-to-implement-oauth2-server-in-expressjs and this documentation: https://oauth2-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html.  I need the oauth2 server to allow the user to enter their username and password to authenticate, so far the /token endpoint takes the username/password combination and returns the json object with the access_token, client_id, etc.  This seems to directly return the access_token and not an authorization_code.  How can I use oauth2-server to authenticate the user with username and password and return the authorization code instead?
